# scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor in Notification Center

Tags: iphone, ios, colors, uicolor

Is there any programatic way to achieve Notification Center background from scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor in Cocoa Touch?

From default scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor

[Default scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/5386/screenshot2011080210123.png](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/5386/screenshot2011080210123.png)

to Notification Center backgound.

[Notification Center backgound http://img98.imageshack.us/img98/7287/screenshot2011080210110.png](http://img98.imageshack.us/img98/7287/screenshot2011080210110.png)

Without No New Notifications label and grate at bottom of course.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use your own background like this [one](http://ihackmyi.com/files/pics/uploads/45621852.jpg)

Comment: nice ... thanks for the link!  Now to just figure out how to code such a drop down view (minus the gestures)

Comment: I'm still interested in knowing how to do this in code.. :/ . I can't see the background file you posted either :/

Comment: @eyalw there is the link on "one" word and image is still there.